# Resetting all fields in a form when it is opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I have two forms that lies under two tabs in a portlet. When I click on tab 2 I want all fields in that form to be empty. I don't want a button. I tried with:

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
         .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}

<input id="button" type="hidden" onclick="resetForm"/></p>
```

but the fields only becomes empty when it is clicked on.

Comment: And where's aforementioned tab 2?

Comment: The text which is shown is in tab 2, In tab 1 there is certain other fields. I want the fields in tab 2 to be emptied from tab 1.

Comment: No, you don't understand. You've shown the resetting code (which, as @kapa rightly mentioned, is easily replaced with a single line), but the problem is about when to call it. Yet you omit any mention of the relevant element in your question - and it's not right.

Comment: I want to call it when tab 2 is clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call:

```
$form.get(0).reset();
```

Using `.get()` you can fetch the DOM element from the jQuery object. The DOM element for the form (`HTMLFormElement`) has a [`reset` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) that will restore the form's default values.

You should put this in the click event handler for your tab 2.

Comment: I don't have a click event handler for the tab. What is that?

Comment: @brbe24 Look it up. I'm asking which is the part of your code that will make your form visible when the user clicks on Tab 2.